# issue with Editor position in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to give Ext.Editor for a panel to inline edit the title of a panel.

```
   var editor = new Ext.Editor({
            updateEl: true,
            ignoreNoChange: true,
            revertInvalid: true,
            width: 235,
            field: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        });

        editor.startEdit(myPanel,myData.value);
```

but the editor is shown 0,0 position, not on my panel as i expected.
How to solve this editor position issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My panel was nested in some other panels and there are some layout issues also. After correcting the layout issues it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be problem with hiding of the bound element which causes the position to fall back to 0,0. Set `hideEl: false` to fix this.